# Python socket, receiving data from multiple clients, inaccurate results

Tags: python, sockets

My code sends packets to a specified range of ip's in my lan and waits for response.
The code works however the results are inaccurate..

Sometimes it gives for example 4 results with different ip's and sometimes 6 results with some different ip's as the previous result.

I know my lan has 12 good results in total, that should be the good amount found.

I don't know where the error in my code lies.

```
def bindupnp():
 s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
 s.bind(("", tport))
 print "Binded ! Waiting to receive some data.."
 return s

def unbindupnp(s):
 print("Unbinding Upnp socket port, waiting 5 results for last results to come in..")
 time.sleep(5)
 s.close() 

def scanupnp(tar):
 try:
  #print "Sending UPNP packets to "+tar
  socketslotupnp.sendto(msg, (tar, upnport))
  string, addr = socketslotupnp.recvfrom(1024)
  upnpdata.append([addr[0], string])
 except Exception as e: print(e)
```

## 1 I bind my port with bindupnp()

## 2 I scan the target hosts in my lan with scanupnp()

## 3 After scanning my whole lan range (192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.255) I unbind again with unbindupnp()

I'm quite new to Python and thought in all possible ways.. Maybe it sounds stupid but I believe each time a response gets received back it "occupies" the socket so other hosts cant send their response back.

Any one has an idea what's going on here and how I can possibly solve it ?

Comment: `socketslotupnp.sendto(msg, (tar, upnport))` will not return until something receives that message.

Comment: socketslotupnp.sendto(msg, (tar, upnport))

Comment: socketslotupnp.sendto(msg, (tar, upnport)) is the socket created in bindupnp() which receives the message back.

Comment: What does that mean

Comment: To be clear the code works only it skips some positive hosts randomly each time..